# Firewall Port Forwardng Required for Xcode Integration?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, port, firewall

To enable VS development of a Xamarin cross platform solution working with a Mac and Xcode behind a Windows Server Firewall, what ports need to be forwarded to the Mac to enable compiling, deployment and debugging on that platform?

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin Agent uses [ssh on port 22](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/firewall#xamarin-mac-agent)

Comment: The troubleshooting page may be useful too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks Guys! I will try those,,,

Comment: Although I am forwarding port 22 to the Mac, I am encountering a "Couldn't retrieve SSH Fingerprint" error when trying to connect. Is something else also needed to be redirected?

Comment: Looking at the troubleshooting tips, I didn't see anything to resolve the issue. 

Are there more details to be found behind the error? Is the error just a timespan error? If I capture the messages between VS and the firewall, are they decipherable?

Comment: there is a section that specifically addresses the "Fingerprint" error

Comment: Looking at the log, it appears that it is a timeout / no response error. I just performed a link locally, .e.g. no firewall, without an issue, and then tried again via the firewall with from the same dialog the timeout error recorded.